# Button title color

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I want  to set button title with underline and of browncolor:

For that I am doing:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *nearestLocation = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Locate Manually"];
[nearestLocation addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                  value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
                  range:(NSRange){0,[nearestLocation length]}];
[btn_manually setAttributedTitle:nearestLocation forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_manually setTitleColor:[UIColor brownColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It is displaying underline but not browncolor.

Comment: You need to set color using NSMutableAttributedString like your underline logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this....

```
 [nearestLocation addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor brownColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,[nearestLocation length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, NSAttributedString is used modifying the text, you can use "NSMutableAttributedString" for multi color text, font, style, etc using single UIButton or UILabel.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The Underlined text"];

// making text property to underline text-
[titleString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];

// using text on button
[btn_manually setAttributedTitle: titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn_manually.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *tempString=@"your string";   
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:tempString];                                                                                     
    int lenght=(int)[tempString length];   
    [attString addAttribute:(id)NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor brownColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,lenght)];  
    [attString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];

    UIButton *hyperLinkButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    hyperLinkButton.frame=CGRectMake(30, 5, 100, 30);
    [hyperLinkButton setAttributedTitle:attString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    hyperLinkButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    hyperLinkButton.tag=[[[[[[personalDetailDictionary objectForKey:@"Acknowledgements"] objectForKey:@"details"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"tagValue"] objectForKey:@"text"] intValue];
    [hyperLinkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hyperLinkAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    hyperLinkButton.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:hyperLinkButton];
```